# Sass: Using Ampersand '&' for body tag which has a specific class

Tags: css, sass

Demo: https://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/WJpPyQ

Assume i have this HTML code:

```
<body class="boxed">
  <div class="text-white">
    <a href="#" class="btn-featured">Button</a>
  </div>
</dody>
```

I'm using this sass code as following:

```
.boxed {
  // error with using "Ampersand"
  body& {

  }
}
```

But it results a compiling error which says:

[image]

Although the result i want is as following:

```
// This the result i want
body.boxed {

}
```

I know that i can use it like this, and it will result what i'm looking for:

```
// I know i can use this
body {
  &.boxed {

  }
}
```

But i want to separate the .boxed class code from inside the body css code for orgnization purpose.

So why this is not allowed although the similar code for element and it's parent is working for the following:

```
// Although this similar code for element and 
// it's parent is working
.btn-featured {
  .text-white & {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

In fact i hope to know why this not allowed!

Comment: Wait, you want the result to be `.boxed {something}` and `body.boxed {something else}` without having to repeat the `.boxed` bit in the SASS. That wasn't very clear at first.

Comment: I want the result to be `body.boxed {something else}` with the scss 
code concept i ask for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello morad you need to use `@at-root`

```
.boxed {
  @at-root body#{&} {
     color: red;
  }
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/NMpJOa)

Comment: Although your technique seems to work, I had to strip out a lot of stuff from your codepen to actually demonstrate it. Here is a better one: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjqBov

Comment: Thanks a lot @patelarpan. This made what i'm looking for :). I want to understand why you used this #{} ?

Comment: Welcome @morad :)

Comment: Here I am using sass interpolation. Here you read about it https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-ever-need-to-know-about-sass-interpolation--cms-21375

Comment: Thanks! I know the interpolation, but i can't imagine what could be the issue that made me have to make interpolation. In fact i tried to remove #{} but it results syntax error.

Comment: If you try to give space between & and body then it will work. But whenever you want to concat two selector or string you need to use interpolation

Comment: Great! I understood now :)

Comment: @xjqBov It works same without needing at-root modifier:
.boxed {
  color: blue;
  div#{&} {
     color: red;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap your selectors around for it to work like you've said.

```
body {
  &.boxed {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

The issue is that the ampersand connects the previous selector to the current selector. So when you do something like this:

```
.boxed {
  body & {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

It's trying to add 'nothing' to the body tag inside an element with the `boxed` class on it. The best way is to do it how you've already stated.

More info on [referencing parent selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector).

Comment: So you mean that the use of Ampersand tried to add parent called `.boxed` which already not parent to body, right? Or the issue is syntax error? Because i think the compilation error that appeared is related to syntax error. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that adding the ampersand going after the class name is a syntax error.